# Creating headers for CSV file

Tags: java, android, opencsv

I'm writing a CSV file using the [Opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net) library and need to add headers to my file. The file is created and the headers are inserted, but **all the headers in same cell**.

```
csvFile.createNewFile();
CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile));
String heading = "eid,name,vid,emp_id,balance_amt,handover_to,entry_date \n";
csvWrite.writeNext(new String[]{heading});
```

Comment: have you tried to seperate the header with a semicolon and not with a comma?

Comment: no how to do that?

Comment: just read the manual: you have to put the header names/values in the array:  String heading = new String() {"eid","name","vid","emp_id","balance_amt","handover_to","entry_date"};

Comment: post that link please

Comment: http://zetcode.com/articles/opencsv/ -> "Writing data"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is your solution :

```
 CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile));
 String[] entries = {"eid","name","vid","emp_id","balance_amt","handover_to","entry_date"};
 csvWrite.writeNext(entries);
```

thats working fine here ! try

Comment: if there is any possible way to change the color for header? bcz some one says its possible to do that..

Comment: Please complete your answer with the library/dependencies (gradle) you are using for this solution, and the configuration code if necessary.

Comment: In this question, you'll get the library and just answering the question that @iam user asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use FileWriter you can make use of:

```
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(CSV_LOCATION); 
    writer.append("Name,Age,Company,Salary");
    writer.append("\n");
```

Comment: if ypu useing fileWRITER THEN THIS WILL WORK