# opencsv writes all columns in one cell

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

There was  a question in the past, and i have the same issue, where i try to create a simple CSV file 
   with column headers as each header is in separate cell, there was similar question back

[Creating headers for CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930398/creating-headers-for-csv-file)

but i am using exactly the same code , and it still writes all the headers in one cell ! Its really irritating , i have the feeling opencsv is somehow not intuitive here, why is this happening ?

```
CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFile));
String[] entries = {"eid","name","vid","emp_id","balance_amt","handover_to","entry_date"};
csvWrite.writeNext(entries);
```

Comment: Can not reproduce, the result I created is "eid","name","vid","emp_id","balance_amt","handover_to","entry_date" in the csv, Can you post the content of the `csvFile` which you find all headers in one cell?

Comment: i get all in one cell, like |id,name,email,country| , not |id|name|.... like i want

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? What you have currently is not enough to demonstrate the problem you have. It seems that you have some custom configuration.(The default separator is ",", but your result is showing "|").